# Error javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: in Decryption

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, keystore, jks

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a String using jks Keystore file.But while decryption i am getting following error...

Here is my class for encryption and decryption :

```
package com.Encrypt;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.UnrecoverableEntryException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Encrypt {

public String encyptCard(String card) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnrecoverableKeyException{
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/keystore/ksjksformat.jks");    
        String keystpassw = "9801461740";
        String alias = "ksjksformat";       
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());                      
            ks.load(is,keystpassw.toCharArray() );          
            Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(alias);            
            PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();          
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(card.getBytes());        
        String cipherData1 = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipherData);
        return cipherData1;             
    }
public String decrypte (String encCardNo) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/keystore/ksjksformat.jks");    
    String keystpassw = "9801461740";
    String alias = "ksjksformat";       
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());                      
        ks.load(is,keystpassw.toCharArray() );      
        Key key = ks.getKey(alias, keystpassw.toCharArray());
        Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(alias);
        PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
        new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) (key));     
        KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keystpassw.toCharArray());
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkentry = (PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(alias, protParam);
        PrivateKey myPrivateKey =pkentry.getPrivateKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myPrivateKey); 
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(encCardNo.getBytes());
        String decrypted =Base64.decodeBase64(cipherData).toString();
        return decrypted;
}
}
```

Here is my class where i am calling these methods : -

```
package com.Encrypt;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableEntryException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
public class CryptoHelper {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws InvalidKeyException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException {

                Encrypt obj = new Encrypt();
                String answerEnc = obj.encyptCard("student");
                System.out.println("encrypted data----------->"+answerEnc);
                String Orginial_data = obj.decrypte(answerEnc);
                System.out.println("Decrypted data-------->"+Orginial_data);

}   
}
```

now i am getting this error : -

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at com.Encrypt.Encrypt.decrypte(Encrypt.java:56)
    at com.Encrypt.CryptoHelper.main(CryptoHelper.java:17)
```

This error is while decryption at line

```
byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(encCardNo.getBytes());
```

in `public String decrypte (String encCardNo)` method. Please explain how can I resolve this one.

Comment: @ Artjom B. ya man this is the actual code . by String student i am getting this exception..:(

Comment: Well, Maarten's answer is correct. I was looking at the encryption function and not into the decryption function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode before decrypting, not after.

As a special service for accepting my answer while posting your own, a bit of a rewrite of `decrypte`:

```
public String decrypte(final String encCardNo) throws IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException {
    // --- setup (should be stored differently)
    final char[] keystpassw = "9801461740".toCharArray();
    final String alias = "ksjksformat";

    // --- retrieve private key from store
    final PrivateKey key;
    try (final FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(
            "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/keystore/ksjksformat.jks")) {
        final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(is, keystpassw);
        key = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, keystpassw);
    } catch (final KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableKeyException | CertificateException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not load key from key store", e);
    }

    // --- initialize cipher
    final Cipher cipher;
    try {
        // should use OAEP instead
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "RSA PKCS v1.5 should always be available", e);
    } catch (final InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Key is not an RSA private key", e);
    }

    // --- decode 
    final byte[] decoded;
    try {
        decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encCardNo);
    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid encoded ciphertext", e);
    }

    // --- decrypt
    final byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(decoded);
    final String cardNo = new String(cipherData, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

    // --- clean up
    try {
        key.destroy();
    } catch (final DestroyFailedException e) {
        // we tried, possibly log this
    }
    Arrays.fill(cipherData, (byte) 0);

    return cardNo;
}
```

Comment: Hi,if i am decoding it before decryption then how it will return correct data.

Comment: Well, the reverse of `card.getBytes()` is `new String(decryptedBytes)` although you may want to specify a character encoding such as `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` for both.

Comment: <br>Hi,<br>if i am decoding it before decryption then how it will return correct data.<br> this is the output when i tried to decode before decryption . Then i output i got is ;;;-----<br>data to encrypte and decypte ->**student**<br>encrypted data withod encoding ->[B@c7e553<br>encrypted data with encoding->hr....(Base 64 encoded data)<br>Decrypted data->[B@1050169.. and That is not **Student**

Comment: can you please explain it little bit more for <br> How to use StandardCharsets.UTF_8 for encoding by code

Comment: You didn't use the String constructor, you just printed out the byte array. Have you even searched for the StandardCharsets class?

Comment: Thanks..now i got..<br> I have to return return new String(cipherData); <br> ..Thanks..Now i am getting the correct answer...

Comment: PS you may want to use a `CharsetDecoder` directly to obtain `char[]`. That way you can zero it after use.

Answer (score 4):

**@Maarten Bodewes** answer is correct we have to decode before decryption ..
Thanks **@Maarten Bodewes**
Here is the code for decryption method which is returning correct output.  
`

```
public String decrypte (String encCardNo) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/keystore/ksjksformat.jks");    
    String keystpassw = "9801461740";
    String alias = "ksjksformat";       
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());                      
        ks.load(is,keystpassw.toCharArray() );      
        Key key = ks.getKey(alias, keystpassw.toCharArray());
        Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(alias);
        PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
        new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) (key));     
        KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keystpassw.toCharArray());
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkentry = (PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(alias, protParam);
        PrivateKey myPrivateKey =pkentry.getPrivateKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myPrivateKey); 
        byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(encCardNo);        
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(decoded);
        return new String(cipherData);      
}`
```

Comment: Took this as input for (untested) example `decrypte`, just to show some coding hints.